# How to find the optimal binary matrix?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, quadratic-programming, binary-programming

I want to solve the following optimisation problem in $W_0 \in \{0,1\}^{m \times k}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \left\| \left\lfloor \frac 1t X_{0} W_{0} \right\rfloor - X_{1} \right\|_F^2\end{array}$$

where $t \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$, $X_1 \in \{0,1\}^{n \times k}$ and $X_0 \in \{0,1\}^{n \times m}$ are given.

I am not sure how to use binary quadratic programming for this problem. Any other suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually we dont define a minimum in a matrix space without a norm.

Comment: Is the problem in going from a (assumed norm, current notation doesn't make sense) of a matrix to a standard vectorized expression, or is it primarily the floor operator you are asking about

Comment: yeah I mean Frobenius norm